# Ffmpeg hangs while transcoding HDHomerun Prime on channel change

Tags: ffmpeg, live-streaming, http-live-streaming

I'm using ffmpeg to transcode a live stream from a HDHomerun Prime. Everything is working beautifully.  However, one ability that I would like, if possible, is the ability to change the channel on the HDHomerun without having to stop and restart the ffmpeg transcoding process.

I start the ffmpeg process to begin reading the UDP feed from the HDHomerun.  It writes the stream to a series of *.ts files with a m3u8 playlist.

The second  I use `hdhomerun_config` to change the channel on the device, ffmpeg immediately reports the following and hangs:

`[mpegts @ 0000018b4e05be60] New video stream 0:3 at pos:295211888 and DTS:40884.7s=108 drop=0 speed=1.02x
[mpegts @ 0000018b4e05be60] New audio stream 0:5 at pos:295279568 and DTS:40884.4s
frame= 4488 fps= 29 q=23.0 q=27.0 q=23.0 size=N/A time=00:02:28.94 bitrate=N/A dup=108 drop=0 speed=0.959x`

The command I am using to launch ffmpeg is:

`ffmpeg.exe -t 03:00:00 -i "udp://192.168.1.150:5000?fifo_size=1000000&overrun_nonfatal=1" -vf yadif=0:-1:1 -y -threads 4 -c:v libx264 -s 1280x720 -r 30 -b:v 4500k -force_key_frames expr:gte(t,n_forced*2) -profile:v high -preset fast -x264opts level=41 -c:a libfdk_aac -b:a 96k -ac 2 -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 6 -hls_wrap 6 -hls_base_url /stream/ -hls_flags temp_file -hls_playlist_type event "C:\temp\streams\4500-stream.m3u8"`

Is there a specific command that I can pass to allow ffmpeg to "recover" from this? Or, is there an arg that prevents this hang in the first place? I'm using the latest version v3.4 of ffmpeg cross-compiled for Windows from Ubuntu. The issue also occurred using the stable version v3.4 of ffmpeg for Windows from ffmpeg.org.

Edit:

A new discovery to the issue, but still not yet resolved:
If I change to the channel BACK to the original channel, Ffmpeg is able to continue writing the stream.

Example: I start on channel X. Ffmpeg is recording to a file.  I change to channel Y. Ffmpeg outputs a message similar to the one posted above and "hangs." I change back to channel X and ffmpeg picks up where it left off, no problem.

Comment: You'll probably have to script fetching the new stream.  I doubt FFmpeg is hanging, it's just that you originally started with one stream and now there's a new irrelevant stream running along side with no more data from the original stream.

Comment: Do you mean start up a new ffmpeg process?

Answer (score 0):

No answer for your issue and too new to comment, but I had been trying to do this for a while based on another software package at https://github.com/bkirkman/hdhrtv

Basically what this implementation is doing is opening a new stream for each channel. I suspect that you will need to do the same and that also explains why when you go "back" the channel resumes itself. Unfortunately, unless you make a playlist and buffer every channel you may not be able to get a solution since the input stream changes.

I'd be interested in taking a look and testing if your willing to share your code.